# Nuget Package manager download issue

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have VS 2010 , when i go to tools/Extension Manager ans start getting Nuget Package manager ,after finishing installation I restart .Net ,but find nothing installed,
PS: I use .NET 4.0..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download Nuget Package manager directly http://nuget.codeplex.com/ from here and after installation restart VS.